How would I go about blending this bezier curve to the plane beneath it?

I have a plane with the texture of a racetrack, as well as a bezier curve mapped to the track layout and the z-axis height of its jumps, I'm just not sure how to proceed in blending the plane to the track so it looks natural.  Can anyone give just some simple guidance, how would I proceed to get the results I want?  Does this have something to do with the shrinkwrap function?



What do you want to happen with the plane regions that don't have a track?

The results you want isn’t completely clear, but I expect you want the otherwise level grass plane to rise up to the edges of the track? As @DanielMöller asked, do you want the regions that are not near the track to just remain flat, or something else?

@TheLabCat Yes, that's what I tried to communicate.

A naive approach is:

Subdivide the plane (the more you subdivide, the steeper the edges of the track, some numbers of divisions provide smoother ramps test some)
Set the position of the points on the plane by raycasting up to hit the track
Use a subdivision surface to smoothen things


